# Netstat for a single connection?

Tags: java, c, networking, network-programming, netstat

On Linux, is there any way to programmatically get stats for single TCP connection? The stats I am looking for are the sort that are printed out by `netstat -s`, but for a single connection rather than in the aggregate across all connections. To give some examples: bytes in/out, retransmits, lost packets and so on.

I can run the code within the process that owns the socket, and it can be given the socket file descriptor. The code that sends/receives data is out of reach though, so for example there's no way to wrap `recv()/send()` to count bytes in/out.

I'll accept answers in any language, but C or Java are particularly relevant hence the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the statistics you see with netstat -s is not kept track of on a per connection basis, only overall counters exists.

What you can do, is pull out the information in /proc/net/tcp

First, readlink() on /proc/self/fd, you want to parse the inode number from that symlink, and match it against a line with the same inode number in /proc/net/tcp , which will contain some rudimentary info about that socket/connection. That fil is though not very well documented, so expect to spend some time on google and reading the linux kernel source code to interpret them.

Answer (score 2):

The information [nos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126769/nos) refers to is available from C with:

```
#include <linux/tcp.h>
...
struct tcp_info info;
socklen_t optlen;
getsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_INFO, &info, &optlen)
```

Unfortunately, as this is Linux specific, it is not exposed through the Java Socket API. If there is a way to obtain the raw file descriptor from the socket, you might be able to implement this as a native method.

I do not see a way to get to the descriptor. However, it might be possible with your own [SocketImplFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketImplFactory.html) and [SocketImpl](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketImpl.html).

It's probably worth noting that the [TCP(7) manual page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html) says this re TCP_INFO:

> This option should not be used in code intended to be portable.

Comment: `getsockopt`'s 5th parameter should be a pointer to a `socklen_t` holding the size of `info`.